# Getting sub string

Tags: c#, string

The question is on C#. 
I have a string "`value1=1234;value2=2345;value3=3456;value4= ..."`

What is the best way to retrieve the values?

I thought about `String.Split(";")` but I don't know how to retrieve the values only. The result I get includes the prefix I don't want.
I only want the values of `"1234", "2345", "3456"...` nothing else, and them put them into a list of strings.

How do I solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the format is always fixed, you can do it fairly easily via LINQ:

```
List<string> values = theString.Split(';').Select(s => s.Split('=')[1]).ToList();
```

Note that you *may* want to use `RemoveEmptyEntries` if your input string ends in a semi-colon:

```
List<string> values = theString
                         .Split(new[]{';'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                         .Select(s => s.Split('=')[1]).ToList();
```

This would prevent an exception from occuring within the `Select`.  If the input doesn't end in a semi-colon, however, this wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Split should remove empty entries, otherwise it would get an empty string as the last value. `.Split(new [] {';'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`

Comment: What if some value has no value? Like "value8=;value9=3333..." Does this still work? What is the result I will get for value8? Null or String.Empty?

Comment: How many strings does this create?

Comment: @Habib It will only do that if there is a semi-colon at the end.  That is an option, if people choose, but without seeing the entire string (the sample didn't have that) it's impossible to know

Comment: @Joey.Lu Yes, it will, since I'm not removing empty entries in the internal split

Comment: @Peri One for each pair in the input string.  If there are 4 values, it'll make 4 strings.

Comment: @Habib I edited to show that as an additional option, with explanation.

Comment: @Reed: I meant in process of creating those four. Each split is creating array of strings. So for four values first split creates four strings, then you split each of them again and create another 8 strings. So 12 strings but only for are result. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @Peri It's creating the first split and building an array, then enumerating through that and creating the others (but allowing the unused to be GC'ed before it goes to the next element).

Comment: @Reed: I'm not sure GC is so clever to collect elements you iterated over. But even if it is why create those unused strings? Many such places in an app or if this code is being called often and your application is waiting for GC instead of doing it's work. I think one should use regular expression here.

Comment: @Peri Regular expressions aren't particularly efficient, either - so you'll be creating some garbage using Regex too.  The GC will collect those strings quickly since they'll all be gen0, though.  The most efficient way (would only do this if profiling showed it was absolutely critical) would likely be to parse it yourself character by character, but that's not very maintainable.

Comment: It probably doesn't matter performance/memory usage wise until we start working with huge strings. I just prefer simple one line var matches = Regex.Matches(toParse, @"=(?<number>(\d+)?)").

Answer (score 4):

```
var text =  "value1=1234;value2=2345;value3=3456;value4= ...";
var pieces = text.Split('=');
var values = new Dictionary<string,string>();

for(int index = 0; index < pieces.Length; index += 2)
{
    values.Add(pieces[index], pieces[index + 1]);
}
```

This will give you a dictionary of the pairs where the key is the left-hand side of the '=' and the value is the string representation of the value, which allows your to do:

```
var value1 = values["value1"];
var value2 = values["value2"];
```